# Store Array to Cookie Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies

I am creating an array in my code which looks like this

`Array [ "type", "year", "week" ]`

When I save this to a cookie and read it again it formats as

`Array [ "type,year,week" ]`

How can I keep the original format `Array [ "type", "year", "week" ]` I guess it is getting stripped down to a CSV when it is added to the cookie.

Thanks in advance

My code:

```
var myArray = [ "type", "year", "week" ]
$.cookie('setup', myArray, { path: '/' }); // set up cookie
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies store *string* values.

You need to serialize your array (with JSON or join with a predefined delimiter) before storing it into a cookie and deserialize it when reading it back.

For example:

```
// store into cookie
$.cookie('setup', myArray.join('|'), { path: '/' });
OR
$.cookie('setup', JSON.stringify(myArray), { path: '/' });

// read from cookie
myArray = $.cookie('setup').split('|');
OR
myArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('setup'));
```

**Note**: The JSON versions are safer since they'll work with any kind of array. The former assumes that your array elements do not contain `|` in them.